# Using OpenGL shaders to plot 4D points in 2D in C++

Tags: c++, opengl

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Visualising 4D objects in OpenGL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6988686/visualising-4d-objects-in-opengl)

I have a set of 4 dimensional data points (lets call the dimensions X,Y,A, and B) that I'd like to plot in 6 different 2d plots (plot XxY, XxA, XxB, YxA, etc...).

In a previous question [I asked about the proper way to store and plot this data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6929927/best-way-to-draw-scatter-plot-with-lots-of-data-points-in-c-using-opengl). The solution was to use a VBO that stored the 4 dimensional vertices.  Then using different vertex shaders I could select which dimensions are plotted in each of the 2d plots.

I've spent a few weeks looking around for openGL tutorials on how to do this but I haven't yet found something that makes sense.

My question is this: In c++, how can I define a shader that would allow me to plot only 2 dimensions of a 4 dimensional point in a VBO, and do I need to define a single shader for all 6 2d plots or do I need a shader for each of 6 different plots?

Finally how do I incorporate the shader into the plotting code so it gets used by openGL?

Comment: maybe, but I'm asking specifically how to do this with shaders whereas the other link is asking for a library.

Comment: The algebra is the same either way. You might as well ask "how do I plot a point using OpenGL shaders"

Comment: Points have 3 dimensions - not 4. So, what is your question?

Comment: @VJo: Three-dimensional points have three dimensions, sure. Four-dimensional points will have four.

Comment: Write down the vector equations without referring to the number of dimensions: it works in equally for any dimensionality.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since shaders can work with 4 dimensional vectors and 4x4 matrix, we can be smart and use only one vertex shader to do the trick. This shader will take three inputs:

- the point data (a 4 floating vector),
- a selection 4x4 matrix,
- a projection 4x4 matrix.

All the magic is done by the selection matrix, which will map you 4 coordinates vector to planar coordinates. Let's call the point data `v`, the selection matrix `S` and `P` the projection matrix. The output of the vertex shader will be:

`P * S * v`

By setting correctly the coefficients of `S`, you will be able to select which component in `v` should appear in the result. For example, if you want to display `YxB`, then `S` will be:

[image: S matrix]

So we have:

[image]

P is a standard projection matrix, which will help you to place your graph correctly (offsets and scale).

Following is an example of vertex shader implementation (not tested, may contain mistakes) for OpenGl3:

```
#version 130

in vec4 vin;
uniform mat4 s;
uniform mat4 p;

out vec4 vout;

void main()
{
    vec4 tmp = s * vin;

    // Depending on your projection matrix,
    // you may force the 4th component to 1.
    tmp[3] = 1;

    vout = p * tmp;
}
```

Notes:
`glUniformMatrix4fv` is the function to use to define `S` and `P`.

Comment: This is the prettiest answer I've seen in a while.

Comment: Of course, you might want to premultiply (`P * S`), instead of using two separate uniforms.

Answer (score 0):

You have this input:

```
in vec4 Points;
```

You can access to vec4 components by indexing them:

```
Point[0]; // Equals Point.x
```

You can supply the following uniforms to specify which components to use for plotting:

```
uniform int XCoordIndex;
uniform int YCoordIndex;

gl_Position = vec4(Point[XCoordIndex], Point[YCoordIndex], 0.0, 1.0)
```